# Is there a list of all Ethiopian coffee-growing regions?

Tags: bean-varieties

Is there a list of the coffee-growing regions of Ethiopia, such as Guji, Yirgacheffe, giving the characteristics of the coffees produced there?

Comment: It might not be the easiest thing to do right now but maybe get in contact with your local library or the library of a nearby university. That's what I did a few years ago when I got into coffee and it helped a lot. Also you might find James Hoffmann's World Atlas of Coffee, which is a really good read.

Answer (score 5):

There is a list in "The World Atlas of Coffee" by James Hoffmann: Sidama, Limu, Jima, Ghimbi/Lekempti, Harrar, Yirgacheffe. All have similar altitude (1400 - 2200 m range) and coffee varieties (heirloom). Also all regions are harvesting around October-February, except Ghimbi (February-April).

Comment: Just be aware that the first edition of this book was published in 2014, meaning the information is now 7 years closer to "outdated". It may or may not still be comprehensive and correct. (I don't have any idea if it is or isn't.) There is a second edition published in 2018 which would be a better source for this information, but I don't own the book and can't say if this specific information changed.